# How to make Mockito arguments match method signature

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to validate that the correct message is logged by my code in an error condition, so I've mocked `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` and I'm trying to verify that it is called correctly.

The signature of the method I'm looking to verify is:  `error(Object, Throwable)`  I'm expecting to have a String passed in that has a variety of other things, but includes the text "Message is too big for queue".  The throwable will be null in this case.

Here is my code to validate this:

```
Mockito.verify(errorLog, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).error(
     Mockito.matches("*Message is too big for queue*"),
     Mockito.isNull(Throwable.class));
```

When this runs, I get an error though:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
log.error(
    matches("*Message is too big for queue*"),
    isNull()
);
-> at com.company.TestClass.testMessageTooBig(TestClass.java:178)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
log.error(
    |ClassUnderTest|Message is too big for queue (size=41). It will never fit, so discarding.,
    null
);
```

It appears that the problem here is that that `Mockito.matches()` makes it look for a method with the signature (String, Throwable) when the actual signature is (Object,Throwable).

How can I make these match?  I know the String is the problem because if I replace the `Mockito.matches()` with `Mockito.any()` it passes.

Comment: What would happen if you removed the leading and trailing asterisks from your argument to Mockito.matches? I'm thinking that might make the regex match.

Comment: [ArgumentCaptor](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) might be an option in your case

Comment: I tried ArgumentCaptor and it didn't help:
`Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
log.error(
    org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor@7ce3cb8e,
    null
);`

Comment: Same for removing the asterisks:
`Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
log.error(
    matches("Message is too big for queue"),
    isNull()
);`

Comment: Here's another detail -- I got rid of the matchers altogether:  

`Mockito.verify(errorLog, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).error(
        (Object) "|ClassUnderTest|Message is too big for queue (size=41). It will never fit, so discarding.",
        null);`

Even with the matchers removed, it still fails:

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
log.error(
    "|ClassUnderTest|Message is too big for queue (size=41). It will never fit, so discarding.",
    null
);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an example would help here. See if you can make sense of this. It may be somewhat contrived, but it should get you a little closer anyway..

Main.java

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class Main {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Main.class);

    public Main(Log l) {
        this.log = l;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main(log);
        m.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        log.info("this is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.", null);
    }
}
```

MainTest.java

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;

public class MainTest {
    Log mockLogger = (Log) Mockito.mock(Log.class);

    private Main testSubject = new Main(mockLogger);

    @Test
    public void should_use_logger() {
        //Mockito.doNothing().when(mockLogger).info(anyString(), any());
        testSubject.go();
        Mockito.verify(mockLogger, Mockito.times(1)).info(contains("emergency broadcasting"), isNull(Throwable.class));
    }
}
```